# How to import photos to keynote IPAD

Tags: ipad, photos, keynote, facebook, import

I have been looking all over the place for a simple answer, I want to make keynote presentations using photos from my company facebook page, I feel like it is impossible there is not a simple import from web option somewhere but I cannot find it and looking on google they want me to download my facebook albums which is not an option with thousands of pictures, someone please help.

Answer (score 1):

You can't import photos directly from Facebook in Keynote for iOS, but you can add photos from your Camera Roll. And the Facebook app for iOS lets you save photos to your Camera Roll -- open the photo in Facebook, then select 'Save Photo' from the top right menu.

You have to repeat this process for each photo you want to include in the presentation, but it's the only way I can think of.